# Best way to display GUI

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I am trying to find out what's the best way to display a *custom design* GUI for a windows application? (I wouldn't mind cross-platform compatibility but windows is enough for now ;) )
I tried using DirectX but the problem with DX is, that you are forced to either use textured quads or render shapes other than quads or triangles with a lot of vertices... I'd prefer NOT to use bitmaps due to the limited resolution. Also a problem with DirectX is, that it doesnt run on systems without a compatible graphics card...

I don't want to use any librarys like Qt or such... I want to do it by myself, I just don't know where to start... Basicly what I'd like to have as a result is something like the GUI of NI's Traktor... (picture below) I have noticed that Traktor runs basicly everywhere (so I think it does not rely on GPU). Any suggestions?

[image: Traktor GUI]

Comment: Well I was aiming more for CPU rendering instead of GPU... Isn't there a way to? And I know Traktor is neither using DX nor OGL to display its GUI...

Comment: Sorry but what is your question? SO is not a discussion forum or "chat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all your drawing in `WM_PAINT`

Use `BeginPaint`
Create your object
`SelectObject`
Draw your stuff or what ever
Then `DeleteObject`

You can even make a colour Transparent
If you want to draw your GUI in a different shap
Use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` set the colour that you want transparent

Also look up Custom Draw
There are alot of examples out there

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with windows, you can use GDI.

> I'd prefer NOT to use bitmaps due to the limited resolution.

You can always create bitmaps dynamically. There are lots of open source libraries to help with the drawing, or you can use GDI for this again.